# How to exclude lowest value from average calculation in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I usually do it in Excel but it is not easy for me to do it in KIBANA as well

I have this table in Excel and every hour I want to average for all instancs in the fiels "detail" but excluding the lowest three values (nine details each hour, the average should be only for the the six highest of them). In Excel I use the LARGE function.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcKO8TGl49dz6usWNwxRx0oVgQb9s_h1/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114168049607741321864&rtpof=true&sd=true

In your opinion is there any chance to do it directly in KIBANA?

No idea how to proceed

Comment: The `kql` tag is for Kusto Query Language

Answer (score 1):

You can use lens  table visualization and set the **number of rows to 6** and **order rows by descending order** of your CPU load. Look at the sample data table here
[image: Example data table]

The average here is calculated for the top 6 values of bytes only.
Here are the settings:
[image: Row settings] [image: Metric settings]

You can try replacing the clientIP here by details and bytes by CPU load

Comment: Thanks Swarna, it works fine but I would like to aggregate all details into one single row. Any chance to have a lens of al lens (nested lens)??

Comment: You can make use of lens table summary row like mentioned above or use lens metrics, to summarize everything as a single metric (You may accept the answer if it helped )

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to automatically remove the last N results from the equation in Kibana. You should be manually filtering out from the list in the visualization every time.

The only alternative I see is to add an extra step that deletes or flags the 3 results per hour you want to exclude, and then in Kibana you just add a regular filter.

The easiest way I can think of is creating a watcher that groups the results by hour, sort by CPU, and then ingest the first 6 results in a different index you can query using Kibana.

Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-alerting.html

If this acceptable for you I can edit this answer with more details about the Watcher I would create.

Comment: Thanks @llermaly I need to deep dive into your suggestion because I never heard about this alerting/watcher

Comment: It is very handful :) , I thought you wanted the detail like the excel you showed. If you need the averages only and the other answer works for you then that one is much better than mine